# javascript events in yii gridview are all fired at once

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, yii

I'm newbie to yii and got a problem with this that made me frustated. I've been searching everywhere but with no luck. I have this gridview below:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'id'=>'leaves-grid',
    'template' => "<div>{pager}</div><div style='float:left;'>{summary}</div><div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div>\n{items}\n<div>{pager}</div><div style='float:left;'>{summary}</div><div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div><br/>",
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'columns'=>array(
        'id_user',
        'id_leaves_type',
        'leaves_from',
        'leaves_to',
        'leaves_desc',
        'leaves_status',
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'template' => '<div class="btn-group">{update}{approve}{disapprove}{cancel}</div>',
            'buttons' => array(
            'update' => array(
                'label' => 'Edit',
                'options' => array('class'=>'btn', 'rel' => ''),
                'visible' => '$data->leaves_status == "Pending"'
            ),
            'approve' => array(
                'label' => 'Approve',
                'icon' => 'ok',
                'options' => array('class'=>'btn btn-delete', 'rel' => ''),
                'click'=>'function(){return confirm("Are you sure you would like to approve this leave?");}',
                'url' => 'CController::createUrl("//hrm/leaves/leaveaction", array("id"=>$data->id_leaves, "type"=>"Approved"))',
                'visible' => '$data->leaves_status == "Pending"'
            ),
            'disapprove' => array(
                'label' => 'Disapprove',
                'icon' => 'hand-down',
                'options' => array('class'=>'btn btn-delete', 'rel' => ''),
                'click'=>'function(){return confirm("Are you sure you would like to disapprove this leave?");}',
                'url' => 'CController::createUrl("//hrm/leaves/leaveaction", array("id"=>$data->id_leaves, "type"=>"Not Approved"))',
                'visible' => '$data->leaves_status == "Pending"'
            ),
            'cancel' => array(
                'label' => 'Cancel',
                'icon' => 'remove',
                'options' => array('class'=>'btn btn-delete', 'rel' => ''),
                'click'=>'function(){return confirm("Are you sure you would like to cancel this leave?");}',
                'url' => 'CController::createUrl("//hrm/leaves/leaveaction", array("id"=>$data->id_leaves, "type"=>"Cancelled"))',
                'visible' => '$data->leaves_status == "Pending"'
            ),
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 150px; text-align: center;'),
        ),
    ),
));
```

Basically, there are 4 buttons at the most right column of a gridview: Edit, Approve, Disapprove, and Cancel and will prompt confirm box before going to the URL listed.

The problem is, when I click one of the button, all click events are fired and confirm boxes are all coming out one after another. What when wrong anyway? Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your code would render the following js

```
$(document).on('click','#leaves-grid a.btn.btn-delete',function(){return confirm("Are you sure you would like to approve this leave?");});
$(document).on('click','#leaves-grid a.btn.btn-delete',function(){return confirm("Are you sure you would like to disapprove this leave?");});
$(document).on('click','#leaves-grid a.btn.btn-delete',function(){return confirm("Are you sure you would like to cancel this leave?");});
```

.....

It would use the final class to assign to click event, then you could see, all of those generatd selectors were the same. To avoid that, you can add specific class in the end of the attribute class looks like

```
'class'=>'btn btn-approve'
'class'=>'btn btn-disapprove'
'class'=>'btn btn-cancel'
```

Comment: Ah yes, I was doing some copy pasting for the buttons and didn't notice that. Thank you very much!